# Unable to call copy constructor

Tags: c++

I am sure , I am missing a simple thing here ,

I am not not able to call copy constructor in the code.
What can be the reason ?

Is compiler optimizing my code ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
int x;
Test(){ 
    x=100;
    cout << "Test() Called\n";
    }
Test(const Test &t) {   
    this->x=t.x;
    cout << "Test-Copy() Called\n";
    }

    };

Test fun()
{
    cout << "fun() Called\n";
    Test t;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
   Test t1;
   Test t2 = fun();
   cout<<t2.x<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: RVO - Return value optimization. The `fun()` returns a temporary - rvalue and hence possibly the compiler is calling the move constructor instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: not a move constructor, I have tried move constructor

Comment: @Vishal when RVO happens, neither move nor copy constructor is called. Also, there is no implicit move constructor because there is a user-declared copy constructor.

Comment: It should not happen in debug build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers may omit the copy- and move-constructors of class objects even if copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. This is called copy ellision.

One such [condition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is:

> If a function returns a class type by value, and the return
>   statement's expression is the name of a non-volatile object with
>   automatic storage duration, which isn't the function parameter, or a
>   catch clause parameter, and which has the same type (ignoring
>   top-level cv-qualification) as the return type of the function, then
>   copy/move is omitted. When that local object is constructed, it is
>   constructed directly in the storage where the function's return value
>   would otherwise be moved or copied to. This variant of copy elision is
>   known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".

If you want to force the call of copy constructor, explicitly break one of the conditions defined above.

Comment: Another option might be to use a compiler switch for disabling copy elision, e.g. gcc has `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: @M.M Thanks. Your comment completes the answer.

Comment: Thank you mohit, that clears my doubt :) . I also got some help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: @KishorBhandari I am glad if it helps you.